# Auto detect only mobile browser (via user-agent?) not tablet

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile, responsive-design

I want to apply meta tag only for mobile devices not for tablet. The purpose is to zoom out the page in mobie devices. I got below condition but the problem is it is also applying on tablet as there is also android tablets.

```
<script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
  || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
    document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=0.25" />');
}
    </script>
```

I know this is an old question but i am not able to find the relevent answer.

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way.  I would look at making your site truly responsive with css.  Check out the bootstrap responsive grid

Comment: We have made the site responsive till tablets but we have different site for mobile devices thats why i want to zoom out the pages only for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Android has "Mobile" string in the User-Agent header. Tablet Android does not. So to get mobile only, you need to search for the word "Mobile" as well as "Android". However there are some tablet companies that are going away from this convention, so for those, like the XOOM, you will need to check for model of the tablet if you want to detect those tablets.

You can also check out this: http://wurfl.io/ . I think this could help by doing something like the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//wurfl.io/wurfl.js"></script>

if(WURFL.form_factor != "Tablet"){
     // do mobile things here
}
```

For context, the script returns a json object like so:

```
{
 "complete_device_name":"Samsung Galaxy Tab",
 "is_mobile":true,
 "form_factor":"Tablet"
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution but i cant use any plugin. Any other solution?

Comment: Like I said in the first part, I think the only other solution is to test for the mobile string in the user agent, and then test for device name for the ones that you know don't have that keyword